# Convert set to string and vice versa

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, set

Set to string. Obvious:

```
>>> s = set([1,2,3])
>>> s
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> str(s)
'set([1, 2, 3])'
```

String to set? Maybe like this?

```
>>> set(map(int,str(s).split('set([')[-1].split('])')[0].split(',')))
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Extremely ugly. Is there better way to serialize/deserialize sets?

Comment: just a note, I've downvoted because the terminology used is wrong. *serialization/deserialization* makes me immediately think of passing objects to/from JSON or via `pickle`, but that's a misleading assumption in this case.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use `repr` and `eval`:

```
>>> s = set([1,2,3])
>>> strs = repr(s)
>>> strs
'set([1, 2, 3])'
>>> eval(strs)
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Note that `eval` is not safe if the source of string is unknown, prefer `ast.literal_eval` for  safer conversion:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> s = set([10, 20, 30])
>>> lis = str(list(s))
>>> set(literal_eval(lis))
set([10, 20, 30])
```

help on `repr`:

```
repr(object) -> string
Return the canonical string representation of the object.
For most object types, eval(repr(object)) == object.
```

Answer (score 13):

The question is little unclear because the title of the question is asking about string and set conversion but then the question at the end asks how do I serialize ? !

let me refresh the concept of [Serialization](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~troy/fall04/cs441/drake/serialization.html) is the process of encoding an object, including the objects it refers to, as a stream of byte data.

If interested to serialize you can use:

```
json.dumps  -> serialize
json.loads  -> deserialize
```

If your question is more about how to convert set to string and string to set then use below code (it's tested in Python 3)

**String to Set**

```
set('abca')
```

**Set to String**

```
''.join(some_var_set)
```

example:

```
def test():
    some_var_set=set('abca')
    print("here is the set:",some_var_set,type(some_var_set))
    some_var_string=''.join(some_var_set)    
    print("here is the string:",some_var_string,type(some_var_string))

test()
```

Answer (score 7):

Try like this,

```
>>> s = set([1,2,3])
>>> s = list(s)
>>> s
[1, 2, 3]

>>> str = ', '.join(str(e) for e in s)
>>> str = 'set(%s)' % str
>>> str
'set(1, 2, 3)'
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants to do.

Comment: Question is : *Python convert set to **string** and vice versa*.

Answer (score 5):

#### 1) Set to String:

`s = set({1,2,3,4}) # set with int values.`

Convert each value of set as a string, and join them to return one string with `,` as a delimiter. 
`str_val = ', '.join(list(map(str, s)))`

output of `str_val`: `'1, 2, 3, 4'`

#### 2) String to Set:

Split the string with `,` as a delimiter. It creates a list. Then convert the list as a set.

`s = set(str_val.split(","))`

output of `s`: `{' 2', ' 3', ' 4', '1'}`

Answer (score 3):

If you do not need the serialized text to be human readable, you can use [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#pickle).

```
import pickle

s = set([1,2,3])

serialized_s = pickle.dumps(s)
print "serialized:"
print serialized_s

deserialized_s = pickle.loads(serialized_s)
print "deserialized:"
print deserialized_s
```

Result:

```
serialized:
c__builtin__
set
p0
((lp1
I1
aI2
aI3
atp2
Rp3
.
deserialized:
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

if the len of the set 1

```
>>> s
{'info@montenegroprospects.com'}
>>> list(s)[0]
'info@montenegroprospects.com'
```

if the set has more than one value

```
>>> def set2str(l, spe=' - '):
       s=''
       for i in l:
            s += f'{i}{spe}'
       return s[:len(s) - len(spe)]
>>> s.add('asfasf')
>>> set2str(s)
'asfasf - info@montenegroprospects.com'
>>> set2str(s,' ') # you can change the spe
'asfasf info@montenegroprospects.com'
```