# How to put string in a set as an individual item?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, iterable

I have a string

```
sample = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
```

I want convert this string to a set

```
final = {"http://www.stackoverflow.com"}
```

I tried the following code:

```
final = set(sample)
```

But i got the wrong out as

```
{u'.', u'/', u':', u'a', u'b', u'c', u'e', u'h', u'i', u'k', u'l', u'n', u'p', u's', u't', u'w'}
```

I also used

```
final  = ast.literal_eval(Sample)
```

and I got this

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there any other solution for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python convert set to string and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528374/python-convert-set-to-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: I tried answers of both Machael and Lutz but I don't know for which answer shall i mark it as correct

Comment: So I will mark according to the oldest post

Comment: You can upvote more than one answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just do it:

```
In [1]: s = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"

In [2]: f = {s}

In [3]: type(f)
Out[3]: builtins.set

In [4]: f
Out[4]: {'http://www.stackoverflow.com'}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
sample = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
final = set((sample, ))
```

Answer (score 7):

The `set()` class ,which is also considered a built-in type, accepts an iterable and returns the unique items from that iterable in a `set` object. Here since strings are considered a form of iterable --of characters-- you can't just call it on your string. Instead, you can either put the string object literally inside a set while defining it or if you're forced to use `set()` you can put it inside another iterable such as list or tuple before you pass it to `set()`.

```
In [14]: s = {'sample string'}                                                                                                                                                                              

In [15]: s                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[15]: {'sample string'}

In [16]: s = set(['sample string'])                                                                                                                                                                         

In [17]: s                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[17]: {'sample string'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is `final = {sample}`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with:

```
final = set(sample.split())
```

And if you had a string separated by spaces, it would leave you each word separated within the set.

```
example= "www.example.com www.natsoft.co www.google.com"

result = set(example.split())
print(result)

{'www.example.com', 'www.natsoft.co', 'www.google.com'}
```